# For loop over a range (Python 2.7 + Ifc)

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, range, ifc

I am quite new to programming, and this is one of my first questions on this site. I've been learning Pyhon for over three weeks now.

For a project I use a module called IfcOpenShell which allow for easy retrieving the data specified in an ifc file. An Ifc file is an express based language to describe building data.

Now I want to retrieve all the relevant material data fit for lighting analyses from an ifc file and convert them to a Radiance format. Radiance is open source lighting analyses software

So far I have written this script:

```
import ifcopenshell

ifc_file = ifcopenshell.open('Example_A.ifc')

materials = ifc_file.by_type('IfcMaterial')

print 'There are ' + str(len(materials)) + ' different types of  materials in the file:' + '\n'

for x in range(0):
    materials = ifc_file.by_type('IfcMaterial')[x] 
    colour = ifc_file.by_type('IfcColourRgb')[x]
    styles = ifc_file.by_type('IfcStyledItem')[x]
    surfacestyles = ifc_file.by_type('IfcSurfaceStyleRendering')[x]

#DECLARING THE VARIABLES FOR RADIANCE DEFINTION
rad_material = materials.Name
rad_red = colour.Red
rad_green = colour.Green
rad_blue = colour.Blue
rad_specular = surfacestyles.SpecularColour
rad_roughness = 0.1 #<- Roughness is not defined in IFC, the value of 0.1 is  merely put there as an example


print 'RETRIEVES DATA FROM IFC FILE PRINTS THEM ACCORDING TO A RADIANCE READABLE DEFINITION'
print ''

print '#material name: ' + rad_material
print '#material type: ' + 'No definition found in the specified ifc file'
print 'void ' + ' plastic ' + rad_material
print '0'
print '0'
print rad_red , rad_green, rad_blue,rad_specular[0], rad_roughness
```

I found there were exactly 100 different materials specified in the ifc file. And when I run this code, it outputs :

```
There are 100 different types of  materials in the file:

RETRIEVES DATA FROM IFC FILE PRINTS THEM ACCORDING TO A RADIANCE READABLE DEFINITION

#material name: SH_resin Floor
#material type: No definition found in the specified ifc file
void  plastic SH_resin Floor
0
0
1.0 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.1
```

This is exactly what I wanted to do, however, when I change:

```
for x in range(0):
```

to

```
for x in range(0,100)
```

it only outputs the last material of the range:

```
There are 100 different types of  materials in the file:

RETRIEVES DATA FROM IFC FILE PRINTS THEM ACCORDING TO A RADIANCE READABLE DEFINITION

#material name: Juice
#material type: No definition found in the specified ifc file
void  plastic Juice
0
0
0.956862745098 0.956862745098 0.956862745098 0.5 0.1
```

I do not understand where I'm making a mistake, or if I'm using the right functions for what I want. My intent was to output all the 100 different material definitions

Comment: You need the indentation of the print statements inside the `for x in range(n)`.

Comment: Is the indentation correct? The only thing that happens in your for-loop is that you assign four variables.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I put my print statements inside the for loop and the code works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation shows which lines is part of the for loop.
If you want the print statements to happen 100 times, you have to indent them as well.

```
import ifcopenshell

ifc_file = ifcopenshell.open('Example_A.ifc')

materials = ifc_file.by_type('IfcMaterial')

print 'There are ' + str(len(materials)) + ' different types of  materials in the file:' + '\n'

for x in range(0):
    materials = ifc_file.by_type('IfcMaterial')[x] 
    colour = ifc_file.by_type('IfcColourRgb')[x]
    styles = ifc_file.by_type('IfcStyledItem')[x]
    surfacestyles = ifc_file.by_type('IfcSurfaceStyleRendering')[x]

    #DECLARING THE VARIABLES FOR RADIANCE DEFINTION
    rad_material = materials.Name
    rad_red = colour.Red
    rad_green = colour.Green
    rad_blue = colour.Blue
    rad_specular = surfacestyles.SpecularColour
    rad_roughness = 0.1 #<- Roughness is not defined in IFC, the value of 0.1 is  merely put there as an example


    print 'RETRIEVES DATA FROM IFC FILE PRINTS THEM ACCORDING TO A RADIANCE READABLE DEFINITION'
    print ''

    print '#material name: ' + rad_material
    print '#material type: ' + 'No definition found in the specified ifc file'
    print 'void ' + ' plastic ' + rad_material
    print '0'
    print '0'
    print rad_red , rad_green, rad_blue,rad_specular[0], rad_roughness
```